# Database Normalisation: Product vs Shape vs Size

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

I am from an optics company. Imagine that we have a flat rectangular glass plate (Length x width x thickness) which is a **parent product** that can be processed into smaller 2D shape **child product** such as circular glass plate, rectangular glass plate or triangle glass plate.

I would like to find a way to store size of that particular shape in a correct manner. For eg, a rectangular part is defined by lengthxwidthxthickness only but not by diameter. A circle is define by diameter and thickness but not by length and width. What is the correct way in keep track this kind of info?

For example, I can have a table which contain the following field:

- ChildProductID
- 2DShapeCategory = {circle, rectangle, triangle}
- DiameterOfCircle
- LengthOfRect
- WidthOfRect
- L1OfTriangle
- L2OfTriangle
- L3OfTriangle

And then for a circular part, the value of that row will be for eg:

```
productID=1 ,shape=circular , diamterofCircle=5 , lengthofRect=0, widthofRect=0, L1ofTriangle=0, L2OfTriangle=0, L3OfTriangle=0
```

then for a rect part, the value of that row can be for eg:

```
productID2, shape=rectangle, diameterofcircle=0, lenghtofRect=10, widthofRect=5, L1ofTriangle=0, L2OfTriangle=0, L3OfTriangle=0
```

But is this a correct way or best practice? I feel not and thus need some help and advice

Comment: This seems like a vague question to me.Unless you are providing more information (such as: what is the objective of this database, is there actually common information between the squares, rectangles and circles which can be stored in a single column, what will be the use-case of the database (will there primarily be insertions or reads on it), etc.) any question will be opinion-based.

Comment: Hi Erik sorry for that. I will edit the question

Comment: Read about 'database/SQL subtyping/polymorphism'. (Frequently wrongly described via implementation antipattern '(multiple'/many) FK(s) to multiple/many tables'.)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Good practice would not include fields that aren't going to hold valid data.  A better way is to use three tables; one for circles, one for triangles, and one for rectangles.  Your parent product table would be `productID` and any fields that are about the parent product itself.  Then you'd have these tables:

Circles_table:

`productID    child_circleID    Diameter`

Rectangle_table:

`productID    child_rectID    length    width`

Triangles_table

`productID   child_triID   L1    L2    L3`

The `productID` field in each table being foreign key that links it to the parent product.